# cuda invalid configuration error 9

Tags: gpgpu, nvidia, gpu

I have a Cuda application; after first allocating cuda memory for various arrays the program loops through:  transfer data to GPU, Process kernels on GPU, transfer data back from GPU.  The first data set is correctly processed by the GPU and returned.  Thereafter subsequent data sets genereate error 9:  Invalid Configuration.

Since I do not de- or re- allocate memory i dont believe i am out of memory.  I have triple-checked the grid and block dimensions and these are well within bounds: ( 200, 0, 0) and (720, 20,0).

What else should i be looking at to understand what is it about the configuration that is invalid ?

Comment: i need to be clearer:  the kernel calls generate the error 9 (the memory copies are without error).  Also, using Nsight the kernel never receives the call;  obviously with a bad configuration the kernel call never gets made.

Answer (score 4):

> I have triple-checked the grid and block dimensions and these are well within bounds: ( 200, 0, 0) and (720, 20,0).

The y and z dimension can not be zero. They have to be at least 1.

=> ( 200, 1, 1) and (720, 20,1)